# Using condition in swift UI view - Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I was making a view which returns a view if the condition is satisfied or an empty view if not.

```
struct CardView: View{
    var card: MemoryGame<String>.Card
    
    var body: some View{
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            self.body(for: geometry.size)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func body(for size: CGSize) -> some View{
        if card.isFaceUp || !card.isMatch{
        ZStack {
            Pie()
                .padding(5)
                .opacity(0.4)
            Text(card.content)
                .font(Font.system(size: min(size.width, size.height) * 0.7))
            }.cardify(isFaceUp: card.isFaceUp)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code, but the error here is with this statement `Text(card.content)`. The error is **`Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred`** and I am not sure about the error or the way to fix it.

Edited:
The code is edited.

Definition of the card is:

```
struct Card: Identifiable{
    var id: Int
        
    var isFaceUp: Bool = false
    var isMatch: Bool = false
        
    let content: CardContent // Card content is of generic type.
}
```

Comment: If you have an `if` statement then you can't rely on the implicit `return`; you need to have an explicit `return`.  You also need something in the `else` case; What will the view contain in that case?

Comment: @Paulw11 Using ViewBuilder if the condition fails it will return an Empty View.

Comment: Hey, could you please include the line where card is declared in your view?

Comment: Yes please, post how `card` is constructed, and what type it is with what properties. It seems that card.content does not conform to StringProtocol. Maybe try casting it to String? Or maybe XCode is again showing a random different error.

Comment: @Paulw11 you do not need neither return nor else this function works perfectly for me with subs for card.isFaceUp, isMatch and content as Bool, Bool and String.

Comment: This code looks like it is lifted from the Standford CS193p course.

Comment: @Andrew yes indeed, It is from CS193p

Comment: @iSpain17 I have updated the code.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to include more information, as it currently stands it is not possible to replicate your code as so many parts of it are missing (You've not included MemoryGame, Pie, the cardify modifier). You need to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we are able to help. Also with SwiftUI, Xcode has a tendency to throw the wrong error, so without more information it is difficult to solve your issue.

Comment: @Andrew I was about to push the code in git and share, but before that I tried to run to be sure, that I have not changed anything and the error is still there. But now it compiles and run as expected. I have not done any changes. Might be xcode and swiftui issue.